# Why isn't it run await

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
print(2);
print(_emailTaken);
print(2);
await isRegister(emailController.value.text);
print(3);
print(_emailTaken);
print(3);
```

and my isRegister method

```
Future<void> isRegister(String email) async {
    fireStore.collection('Users').doc(email).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      print(1);
      print(ds.exists);
      print(1);
      _emailTaken = ds.exists;
    });
  }
```

but output is

I/flutter (20531): 2

I/flutter (20531): false

I/flutter (20531): 2

I/flutter (20531): 3

I/flutter (20531): false

I/flutter (20531): 3

I/flutter (20531): 1

I/flutter (20531): true

I/flutter (20531): 1

Why don't wait in the await syntax?

Comment: oh, I'm not sure to understand what you wanna do, could you explain?

Comment: It'll only await if used inside an async function.

Answer (score 2):

You are not awaiting the get inside you register function. So to fix it change it to the following:

```dart
Future<void> isRegister(String email) async {
   await  fireStore.collection('Users').doc(email).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      print(1);
      print(ds.exists);
      print(1);
      _emailTaken = ds.exists;
    });
  }
```

Or:

```dart
Future<void> isRegister(String email) {
   return fireStore.collection('Users').doc(email).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      print(1);
      print(ds.exists);
      print(1);
      _emailTaken = ds.exists;
    });
  }
```

Comment: and of course `Future<void> isRegister(...` method should be something like: `Future<bool> isRegister(...` - then that ugly global `_emailTaken` is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `awaiting` inside your `isRegister` as Kishan suggested, you could also return the `Future`:

```
Future<bool> isRegister(String email) {
  return fireStore
      .collection('Users')
      .doc(email)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) => _emailTaken = ds.exists);
}
```

*Note: An added benefit is that the return of `isRegister` is now a `Future<bool>`. The result is still cached in `_emailTaken` for future reference, but is also directly returned by your method.*

### Minimal Working Example with `return`:

```dart
bool x = false;

Future<bool> _fetchData() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => x = true);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print('1. $x');
  print('2. ${await(_fetchData())}');
  print('3. $x');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('4. $x');
}
```

Results in:

```
1. false
2. true
3. true
4. true
```

### Minimal Working Example without `return`:

```dart
bool x = false;

Future<void> _fetchData() async {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => x = true);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print('1. $x');
  await(_fetchData());
  print('3. $x');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('4. $x');
}
```

Results in:

```
1. false
3. false
4. true
```